# What is the first sci-fi time travel movie where a person can travel back in time, not instantaneously, but at the rate of 1s per second?

Tags: movie, time-travel, history-of

In most movies that feature time travel, traveling back in time is instantaneous or takes just a few seconds, regardless of how long ago a person travels back. The exceptions I know of are two of my favorite time-travel movies: [*Primer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(film)) (2004) and [*Tenet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenet_(film)) (2020). In those movies, say you want to travel back one week ago, it would also take you one week before you reach that point in time. Time traveling will be trickier, the longer ago you want to travel back.

In *Primer*, time traveling is done by staying inside the time machine, a coffin-shaped box. You'd have to take oxygen, water, and other necessities inside the box with you until you get back to the point in time you're traveling to. In *Tenet*, you go into one side of the time machine, called a "turnstile", then go out the other side "inverted" — traveling back in time at the same rate as regular forward time; the rest of the world will appear to be moving backward from your point of view, making for exciting fight scenes and car chases between inverted and non-inverted people.

**What is the first science fiction movie that featured similar time travel *technology*, where traveling back in time is not instantaneous, but takes place at the same rate as regular forward time — one second per second?** *Primer* is the oldest I can think of, but perhaps this has been done in a prior movie.

Note: I'm looking for a movie where time traveling is *technological* in nature, and not magical, supernatural, or unexplained.

Comment: Would groundhog Day count as a time travel movie as per your definition?

Comment: @A.Steer No. The time travel in *Groundhog Day* is not through technological means.  The backward time travel is also not at the rate of 1s / second.

Comment: Would Merlin from The Once and Future King count as a time traveler? He lived his life backwards so from his perspective he was always traveling back in time at a rate of 1 s/second.

Comment: To travel back in time at the rate of one second per second means negating the usual forward travel of one second per second. You ain't going nowhere.

Comment: Not a movie, burt there is a short story called [_The Very Slow Time Machine_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/698910.The_Very_Slow_Time_Machine) by Ian Watson from 1979...

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron That is the same as saying that to travel to the west, you need to be going faster than 1666 km/h, otherwise you're travelling east!

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron "*To travel back in time at the rate of one second per second means negating…*" When I drive my car in reverse, the speedometer doesn't say negative  km/h. Nor does the number on my odometer go lower when I drive in reverse. The same concept applies here.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Is that a movie? I'm not familiar with it. If that's a movie and the time traveler used technological/scientific means to travel back in time, then yes. Otherwise, if the time travel method is magical or unexplained, then no.

Comment: @galacticninja It is a book but it has been adapted into many movies, like Disney's The Sword in the Stone for example. However, it is by unexplained and presumed supernatural means, and not technological so I guess it doesn't count.

Comment: @galacticninja Well, in that case, we are discussing a semantic problem. If you reverse your car, you have to slow down first. What I meant was that if you want to travel back in time, first you have to slow your forward advance to zero before going into reverse, as you put it. This will require energy, will it not?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron The question says nothing about the transition from forwards to backwards. Certainly, going from travelling East at 1 metre per second to travelling West at 1 metre per second requires an initial westwards acceleration to first stop, then reverse direction, but the end result is a *speed* of 1 metre per second, not more. Similarly, our normal experience of time is a constant "speed" of 1 second per second in the direction of the future; after some appropriate "acceleration", you can have a constant "speed" of 1 second per second in the direction of the past.

Comment: It does work in the opposite direction though.  I've been travelling forward in time at a rate of 1 second per second for quite some time now.

Comment: I believe there was a question where they asked something very similar, about stories where they went -1s